# Crontab except specific hours

Tags: linux, unix, cron

I would like to run Crontab every 30 minutes except from `12 AM - 6 AM EST`

The following is to set it every 30 minutes but i don't know how to except the mentioned hours.

```
*/30 * * * *
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want this rule:

```
0 0,30 6/1 ? * * *
```

This runs at 0 minutes and 30 minutes past the hour, and every hour after the 6th hour.

This assumes that your system timezone is in an ET timezone like `America/New_York`

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me out. much appreciated